# DBI General Network error to SQL Server - nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, connection, r-dbi

I am  trying to connect to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server with DBI package.
The table have 17million rows.

I'm using DBI package and i try two way:

```r
    # libraries
    library("DBI")
    library("tidyverse")
    library("tictoc")
    library("dplyr")
    library("dbplyr")
    
    # open connection to MS SQL server
    conSql <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                             database = 'database',
                             SERVER_NAME_SQL,
                             uid = userIdSql,
                             pwd = passwordSql)
                             
    # --------------------------------
    # 1st way - dbGetQuery
    # --------------------------------
    
    # extract all rows
    mp_jobOrdersItems_17mil <- dbGetQuery(conSql, "select * from dbo.table_17ml")        %>%
      as_tibble
    
    # --------------------------------  
    # 2ndway - dbSendQuery and multiple dbFetch
    # --------------------------------
    
    # Fetch in chunks
    rs <- dbSendQuery(conSql, "select * from dbo.table_17ml")
    
    # loop
    while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
        chunk <- dbFetch(rs, 1000)
        print(nrow(chunk))
    }
    
    # clear results
    dbClearResult(rs)
    
    
    # close Connection
    DBI::dbDisconnect(conSql)
```

Summary:

- with `r dbGetQuery()` i can only download less than 100k  rows
- with `r dbSendQuery()` and `r dbFetch()` i tried in one shot or multiple fetch, i can only dowload less than 200k rows
- if i try with all table rows i receive the error below

I receive the error:

> Error in result_fetch(res@ptr, n) :    nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:2695:
> HY018: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionWrite
> (send()).  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]General
> network error. Check your network documentation.

I test without problems:

- connection
- I saw the table with Rstudio connection interface
- I can read a small sample and took in R in a data.frame or tibble

Can anyone help me or give me some advice?

thanks in advance

MC

*Environment information:*

*R INFO*

```
R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dbplyr_2.1.0    tictoc_1.0      forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.5     purrr_0.3.4     readr_1.4.0     tidyr_1.1.3    
 [9] tibble_3.1.0    ggplot2_3.3.3   tidyverse_1.3.0 DBI_1.1.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.6       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.5.1     compiler_4.0.4   tools_4.0.4      odbc_1.3.1       bit_4.0.4        lubridate_1.7.10
 [9] jsonlite_1.7.2   lifecycle_1.0.0  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.10     reprex_1.0.0     cli_2.3.1        rstudioapi_0.13 
[17] haven_2.3.1      withr_2.4.1      xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2       fs_1.5.0         generics_0.1.0   vctrs_0.3.6      hms_1.0.0       
[25] bit64_4.0.5      grid_4.0.4       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.2       R6_2.5.0         fansi_0.4.2      readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.8    
[33] blob_1.2.1       magrittr_2.0.1   backports_1.2.1  scales_1.1.1     ellipsis_0.3.1   rvest_1.0.0      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_2.0-0
[41] utf8_1.2.1       stringi_1.5.3    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.5      crayon_1.4.1
```

*SQL SERVER INFO*

```
Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Feb  4 2021 02:12:36   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
```

*odbc list*

```
                                name        attribute value
1                         SQL Server         APILevel     2
2                         SQL Server ConnectFunctions   YYY
3                         SQL Server        CPTimeout    60
4                         SQL Server    DriverODBCVer 03.50
5                         SQL Server        FileUsage     0
6                         SQL Server         SQLLevel     1
7                         SQL Server       UsageCount     1
8      SQL Server Native Client 11.0       UsageCount     1
9      SQL Server Native Client 11.0         APILevel     2
10     SQL Server Native Client 11.0 ConnectFunctions   YYY
11     SQL Server Native Client 11.0        CPTimeout    60
12     SQL Server Native Client 11.0    DriverODBCVer 03.80
13     SQL Server Native Client 11.0        FileUsage     0
14     SQL Server Native Client 11.0         SQLLevel     1
15     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server       UsageCount     1
16     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server         APILevel     2
17     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server ConnectFunctions   YYY
18     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server        CPTimeout    60
19     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server    DriverODBCVer 03.80
20     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server        FileUsage     0
21     ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server         SQLLevel     1
22    MongoDB ODBC 1.4.2 ANSI Driver       UsageCount     1
23 MongoDB ODBC 1.4.2 Unicode Driver       UsageCount     1
```

**UPDATE: 1/Apr/2021**

Comment: What code are you using to read the data? Can you use `dbSendQuery()` and then repeated calls to `dbFetch()`? (Don't forget to clear with `dbClearResult()` .)

Comment: thanks for comment!
I'm using dbSendQuery: 

`conSql <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), database = 'schema', SERVER_NAME_SQL, uid = userIdSql, pwd = passwordSql, timeout = 3600)

# extract data
df_result <- dbGetQuery(conSql, "select top 90000 * from dbo.table") %>% as_tibble`

Comment: Thanks. Would you mind editing your post and adding this info? -- Can you replace `dbGetQuery()` by `dbSendQuery()` without `LIMIT` and multiple `dbFetch()` calls, followed by `dbClearResult()` ?

Comment: Thank @krlmlr! 

I tried with dbFetch different test: 

1. if i try on all rows i'll received the same error, i use "top n rows" in query i dowloaded 200k, before i stopped at 100k.  

2. using dbFetch multiple without lmit to 200k rows but after 200 iterations with n = 1000 i received the same error: 

`rs <- dbSendQuery(conSql, "select * from dbo.mp_jobOrdersItems_17mil")

#loop
while (!dbHasCompleted(rs)) {
    chunk <- dbFetch(rs, 1000)
    print(nrow(chunk))
}

# clear results
dbClearResult(rs)`

Comment: Too bad. How many columns does your table have? Does the number increase if you select only a few of them? What does `odbc::odbcListDrivers()` show?

Comment: @krlmlr Table has 40 columns, i tried to query all table with 12 columns or only 1 but i received the same error. i update the post with the odbc's list drivers. I guess it could be a database network setup problem.